# Can't access PostgreSQL from outside of the server

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2008

Can't access PostgreSQL from outside of the server

I already have 2 instances of PostgreSQL database on my server, but they were configured not by me. Both databases are lunched as service on Windows Server. There is a column 'Log On As' where values for PostgreSQL services are 'Network Service'.

I created another instance of PostgreSQL and added it to the service via pg_ctl.exe. Everything is exactly the same as other services have. One different is that value for 'Log On As' is set to '.\postgres'. If I change it to 'Network Service', then I recieve the next message in service startup:

> The "servicename" service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

If it set to '.\postgres' or 'Local System' then database can be lunched and I can access it via pgAdmin (if it is on local server). But I can't access this database from outside of the server.

In postgresql.conf I only set listen_addresses and port.

The problem might be in router, but I want to know that this 'Log On As' is not a root of the problem.

Comment: 'Log On As' is very unlikely the cause. Are you sure that the port used for the new instance is not used by anything else? Also, you might need to open the new port in the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Yes, port is not used by anything else and I opened it in the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the new PostgreSQL server via pgAdmin or psql on the same computer but specifying the external IP address instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Now tried. I can't connect to my or already existing databases by the external IP address.

Comment: Make sure connection-related logging is turned on. Check this by connecting locally. Then try again remotely and see if you get anything logged. If not, it's something in your network setup

Comment: Well, logging is working locally. I tried remote connect to the existing databases and this was logged. After that I tried to connect to my new database and nothing happens. After that I tried to connect directly to the server via IP and my db log wrote this line: "invalid length of startup packet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem when I can't start PostgreSQL service with 'Network Service' as 'Log On As' was caused by lack of permissions to data folder for this user. I just added 'Network Service' in the Security tab with Full control permissions and this solved this small problem.

But the problems, when I can't access my database from outside of my server were caused by network settings. I configured my router and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The access from external IP should be allowed explicitly in pg_hba.conf - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Yes, I added line "host    DBname     all        0.0.0.0/0                 md5" to this file. Other instances have the same line and they are working normally.

Comment: @Serbin - did you reload?

Comment: Yes, of course. I reloaded services and server as well.